# Printf long long int in C with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, c99

How do I printf `long long int` and also `unsigned long long int` in C99 using GCC?

I have searched the other posts which suggest to use `%lld` but it gives these warnings:

> warning#1: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat]|
>   warning#2: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|

For the following attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   long long int x = 0;
   unsigned long long int y = 0;
   printf("%lld\n", x);
   printf("%llu\n", y);
}
```

Comment: Did you use the `-std=c99` flag when compiling?

Comment: I get no warnings: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)

Comment: @netcoder: I'm not sure how to look for the version. I'm running gcc on windows x86.

Comment: Ah, it's gcc version 4.6.1. Thanks @effeffe.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Well, reading the accepted answer and since GCC changes report doesn't mention this issue, that could be the problem. I'd try anyway to update the compiler.

Comment: @effeffe: Windows xp service pack 3.

Comment: @H2CO3, @effeffe: I just found that I didn't have `-std=c99` flag set. I thought that it was globally set for all projects. The program that I have in example compiles without any warnings. I apologize for any trouble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MinGW GCC: "Unknown conversion type character 'h'" (snprintf)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678124/mingw-gcc-unknown-conversion-type-character-h-snprintf)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you are on windows and using mingw, gcc uses the win32 runtime, where printf needs `%I64d` for a 64 bit integer. (and `%I64u` for an unsinged 64 bit integer)

For most other platforms you'd use `%lld` for printing a long long. (and `%llu` if it's unsigned). This is standarized in C99.

gcc doesn't come with a full C runtime, it defers to the platform it's running on - so the general case is that you need to consult the documentation for your particular platform - independent of gcc.

Comment: I agree to you and moderators too, but the SO isn't really for this type of thread... by keeping your comment here may become chaos.

Comment: So, Is it a non-standard way to do it in windows? Any other compiler may I know which fully supports and follows standard rules for windows x86?

Comment: @user963241 Not on windows, afaik.

Comment: Could we open a chat about this?

Comment: @nos: As I know `h` modifies the length of decimal to `short`. Any idea about if `hh` works well in windows on gcc and what it does?

Comment: Warning: do not confuse the uppercase "i" in "%I64d" with lowercase L. I just did that mistake.

Comment: It may be worth noting that defining `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` will make mingw use a standard stdio. This is useful also because windows' printf doesn't understand %n.

Comment: Note that msvcrt of modern Windows (after Windows XP) does support `%lld %llX`. To get the program work consistently, you may use the method mentioned by @Shahbaz so you don't have to use that weird `%I64d` stuff.

Answer (score 7):

For portable code, the macros in [inttypes.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) may be used. They expand to the correct ones for the platform.

E.g. for 64 bit integer, the macro `PRId64` can be used.

```
int64_t n = 7;
printf("n is %" PRId64 "\n", n);
```

Comment: As much as I hate those macros this should be the correct answer - though it came late. Btw `int64_t` is not guaranteed to exist. The _least versions are guaranteed. Perhaps you already know that though.

Comment: Some MinGW versions define `PRId64` to `lld` yet they still complain that `%lld` is not valid. Note that OP's problem stems from using MinGW.

Answer (score 3):

Try to update your compiler, I'm using GCC 4.7 on Windows 7 Starter x86 with MinGW and it compiles fine with the same options both in C99 and C11.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the changes log for GCC 4.7 version?

Comment: @user963241: hmm, can't find anything... http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/ maybe it's about MinGW, but I can't access their site at the moment.

Comment: Did the latest GCC 4.7 compiler come with MinGW? I have just tried to download and install MinGW but it didn't update my compiler to version 4.7.

Comment: I have it, so yes. Maybe you're still using the old version someway.

Comment: I think it could be that I'm using an old version of Windows and not the compiler. I'll try with latest compiler anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You can try settings of `code::block`, there is a complier..., then you select in C mode.

[image]

Comment: Just to give you reasons why your answer might have been voted down. It doesn't answer the question. It assumes the OP is using a specific tool. And maybe even more importantly it doesn't tell the OP _how_ it's actually done - it just lets the tool do it for you. That's not good.  Btw I didn't down-vote you as I know you tried but if someone is trying to learn how to do something telling them a tool that will do it for you is not going to teach them anything at all.