# How can I work around int overflow in c

Tags: c

In C, is it possible to do the below operation without causing an integer overflow?
My answer needs to be an integer which I use later on in the program. The code prints -337.
The correct answer should be 2014.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
   int i;
   i = (10000 * 735625 + 14780)/3652425;
   printf("%d",i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to use `long long` instead.

Comment: Any reason why you use such a strange formula if you know the result already?

Comment: Just change `10000` to `10000LL` and you should be set. That changes the calculation to use `long long`, which has higher precision. The result will (in this case) still fit in a regular `int`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. You were spot on.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. You were spot on. And in answer to your question deviantfan, one of the numbers in the formula :735625 is a calculated variable g in my program. It served no purpose to write out my whole programe here. You only need an instance of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [usual arithmetic conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx), it will overflow as `10000 * 735625 + 14780` (out of `int`'s range) is trying to save into `int`.

> Integral promotions are performed on the operands as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of type `unsigned long`, the other operand is converted to type `unsigned long`.
> - If preceding condition not met, and if either operand is of type `long` and the other of type `unsigned int`, both operands are converted to type `unsigned long`.
> - If the preceding two conditions are not met, and if either operand is of type `long`, the other operand is converted to type `long`.
> - If the preceding three conditions are not met, and if either operand is of type `unsigned int`, the other operand is converted to type `unsigned int`.
> - **If none of the preceding conditions are met, both operands are converted to type `int`.**

To work out, you need to use `long long` (with larger range) stead.

A simple way, as @JoachimIsaksson suggested, is to put `LL` after `10000` to calculate with `long long`'s precision:

```
i = ( 10000LL * 735625 + 14780)/3652425;
```

See it live: [`http://ideone.com/pA2Pvm`](http://ideone.com/pA2Pvm)

Comment: Also make sure you change the `printf` specifier from `%d` - [How to print 'long long int' in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590735/printf-long-long-int-in-c-with-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

```
i = (int)((10000.0 * 735625.0 + 14780.0)/3652425.0);

printf("%d",i);
```

valter