# Getting weird result by using %I64u inside Mingw-w64

Tags: c++, windows, printf, scanf

This is my code :

Note : \n inside scanf is my way to prevent trailing newline problem. That isn't best solution but i'm using it too much and currently it becoming my habit. :-)

```
...

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int input[2], calc_square;

    while(scanf("\n%I64u %I64u", input[0], input[1]) == 2)
    {
        printf("%I64u %I64u\n", input[0], input[1]);

        ...
```

My expected input and program result is :

Input :

```
89 89
```

For output, instead of printing back 89, it show this output :

```
I64u I64u
```

I'm using g++ (GCC) 4.9.1 from MSYS2 package. Noted that g++ because there are some portion of my code currently using C++ STL.

---

Edited : I changed my code by using standard `%llu` instead of `%I64u`, and here is my expected input and program result :

Input

```
89 89
```

For output, it's kind a weird result :

```
25769968512 2337536
```

Comment: From the `printf` example it should be clear that g++ does not support the `I64` modifier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printf long long int in C with GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590735/printf-long-long-int-in-c-with-gcc)

Comment: @RaymondChen, I already take a look at that, but i'm became confuse with I64u output, so because of that I created this new question. Thank you for clear this thing up for me. :-)

Comment: Using non-standard specifiers causes undefined behaviour; to solve this use `%llu`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, this is my result for using `%llu`, input is both 89, and output is `25769968512 2337536`

Comment: post a MCVE plus input, and change your code to check the result of `scanf`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I don't clear insight regarding MCVE plus input, for your second request, I has already edited it.

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean but I can't guess what you have put in "..." or how you are compiling your program.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, sorry if I not clearing this thing up for you, here is my complete code, http://pastebin.com/cJyeaNB9, and here is how i'm compiling my code, `g++ code.cpp -o code.exe`

Comment: @MohdShahril take out all the stuff not relevant to the problem, and use `-std=c++11` in the compilation, and check the return value of scanf.  C++03 didn't have `long long`.

Comment: BTW in the pastebin code, `arr[i]` accesses out of bounds of the vector when `i == 1` ; vectors index from `0`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, using `-std=c++11` didnt solve this problem, BTW, for out of bound, it's actually coding mistake. BTW, I'm now planning to change all my code into C, and thanks for helping me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
while(scanf("\n%I64u %I64u", input[0], input[1]) == 2)
```

`input[0]` and `input[1]` each have type `unsigned long long`, but they are required to have type `unsigned long long *` (*pointer* to `unsigned long long`) for `scanf` operations.  I'm unsure if MinGW supports checking `printf` and `scanf` format specifiers, but ordinary GCC is capable of detecting these kinds of errors at compile time **as long as you enable the proper warnings**.  I highly recommend always compiling with as high of a warning level as you possibly can, such as `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` in the most extreme case.

You need to pass in the *address* of these variables:

```
while(scanf("\n%I64u %I64u", &input[0], &input[1]) == 2)
//                           ^          ^
//                           |          |
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't noticed this much earlier, BTW, for G++, I'm using `%llu` instead of `%64u` and it's working for me. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have been using MSYS2's GCC which isn't a native Windows compiler, and doesn't support the MS-specific %I64 format modifiers (MSYS2's GCC is very much like Cygwin's GCC).

If you wanted to use MinGW-w64 GCC, you should have launched mingw64_shell.bat or mingw32_shell.bat and have the appropriate toolchain installed:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
```

or

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

With that done, you can safely use either modifier on any Windows version dating back to Windows XP SP3 *provided* you pass -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1.

FWIW, I avoid using the MS-specific modifiers and always pass -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1

Finally, annoyingly, your sample doesn't work when launched from the MSYS2 shell due to mintty not being a proper Windows console; you need to run it from cmd.exe