# How do I use larger integers in a C program?

Tags: c, integer, long-long

I'm using Codeblocks and the GNU compiler on a Windows computer. When the compiler runs, it does so under the following conditions:

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -std=c11 <filename> -o obj\Debug\main.o
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("INTEGER min: %d\n", INT_MIN);
    printf("INTEGER max: %d\n\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("UNSIGNED INTEGER max: %u\n\n", UINT_MAX);
    printf("LONG INTEGER min: %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
    printf("LONG INTEGER max: %ld\n\n", LONG_MAX);
    //printf("LONG LONG INTEGER min: %lld\n", LONG_LONG_MIN);
    //printf("LONG LONG INTEGER max: %lld\n\n", LONG_LONG_MAX);
    printf("UNSIGNED LONG INTEGER max: %lu\n\n", ULONG_MAX);
    //printf("UNSIGNED LONG LONG INTEGER max: %lld\n", ULONG_LONG_MAX);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My output for this code:

```
INTEGER min: -2147483648
INTEGER max: 2147483648

UNSIGNED INTEGER max: 4294967295

LONG INTEGER min: -2147483648
LONG INTEGER max: 2147483648

UNSIGNED LONG INTEGER max: 4294967295
```

The lines referring to LONG LONG integers are commented out because the compiler was giving errors:

```
error: 'LONG_LONG_MIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'LONG_LONG_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'ULONG_LONG_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

However, while typing the code, CodeBlocks provided code hinting indicating that I could, in fact, use the LONG_LONG constants. Hence, I need answers for the following questions:

1. Why do the integers and long integers have the same limits? Shouldn't the long integers have a larger range of values?
2. Why am I having trouble with the LONG_LONG constants? Does this mean I can't use long long integers?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate question. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590735/printf-long-long-int-in-c-with-gcc

Comment: @JamesMcCormac: related, but definitely a different question.

Answer (score 9):

The constants you're looking for are not called `LONG_LONG_...`. Check your `limits.h` header. Most likely you're after `ULLONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MAX`, etc.

Comment: Thanks...that solved the second question.  However, what about the first?

Comment: Also, I got the LONG_LONG constants from `limits.h`. It contains both sets of constants. Obviously, I have no idea why. :)

Answer (score 5):

The constants are `LLONG_MAX`, `ULLONG_MAX`, etc.

As to why `int` and `long int` have the same value, blame the C standard: it does not define a fixed number of bits for each data type, only the minimum number of bits:

- `int` must be at least 16 bits
- `long int` must be at least 32 bits
- `long long int` must be at least 64 bits

The exact number of bits differ from OS to OS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("INTEGER min: %d\n", INT_MIN);
    printf("INTEGER max: %d\n\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("UNSIGNED INTEGER max: %u\n\n", UINT_MAX);
    printf("LONG INTEGER min: %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
    printf("LONG INTEGER max: %ld\n\n", LONG_MAX);
    printf("LONG LONG INTEGER min: %lld\n", LLONG_MIN);
    printf("LONG LONG INTEGER max: %lld\n\n", LLONG_MAX);
    printf("UNSIGNED LONG INTEGER max: %lu\n\n", ULONG_MAX);
    printf("UNSIGNED LONG LONG INTEGER max: %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On my Mac OS X, 64-bit, that prints:

```
INTEGER min: -2147483648
INTEGER max: 2147483647

UNSIGNED INTEGER max: 4294967295

LONG INTEGER min: -9223372036854775808
LONG INTEGER max: 9223372036854775807

LONG LONG INTEGER min: -9223372036854775808
LONG LONG INTEGER max: 9223372036854775807

UNSIGNED LONG INTEGER max: 18446744073709551615

UNSIGNED LONG LONG INTEGER max: 18446744073709551615
```

---

**Edit:** if you want to write portable code and have fixed-width integers, use `stdint.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

printf("int64_t max : %lld\n\n", INT64_MAX);  // 9223372036854775807
printf("uint64_t max: %llu\n\n", UINT64_MAX); // 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Ok.  After fixing the long long constants, I get the same value you show for long long integers. So, basically, if I need to use an integer larger than INTEGER, I will need to use LONG LONG INTEGER?

Comment: Thank you much...that's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do the integers and long integers have the same limits? Shouldn't the long integers have a larger range of values?

You have stepped into one of the hallmarks of the C language - its adaptability.

C defines the range of `int` to be at least as wide as `short` and the range of `long` to be at least as wide as `int`.  All have minimum ranges.

Rather than precisely defined the range of `short, int, long`, C opted for versatility.  On OP's platform, the range of `int` matches the range of `long` (32-bit).  On many embedded processors of 2016 (and home computers of the 70s,80s), the range of `int` matches the range of `short` (16-bit).  On some platforms (64-bit) the range of `int` exceeds `short`, and *narrower than* `long`.  So directly to OP's question: **`int` does not always have the same range as `long`.**

The trick is that `int` is not just another rung of the `singed char, short, int, long, long long` ladder.  It is *the* integer type.  Given the *usual integer promotions*, all narrows types promote to `int`.  `int` is *often* the processor's native bit width.

Most code has been written with `int` as 32-bit and also a large percentage as 16-bit.  With 64-bit processors, having `int` as 64-bit is possible, but that leaves only 2 standard type for `signed char, short` for 8, 16 and 32-bit.

Going forward, simple count on `signed char` range `<=` the `short` range, `short` range `<=` the `int` range, **`int` range `<=` the `long` range**, etc.  Also that `signed char` is at least 8-bit, `short, int` at least 16-bit, `long` at least 32-bit, `long long` at least 64-bit.  If code needs explicit widths, use `int8_t`, `int16_t`, etc.

The fact that C is used 40+ years later attests that this versatility has/had merit.

[Discussion omits unsigned types, `_Bool_t` and `char` for brevity.  Also omitted are rare non-power-of-2 types (9, 18, 24, 36 etc.)]

Comment: Also note this is because Windows chose the dummy [LLP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). With LP64 (chosen by most linux systems) longs are 64-bits integers.

Comment: @jdarthenay Thanks for the useful reference.

Answer (score 1):

Besides limits.h on a system with specific implementation, also check out what the C standard defines the limits of the various integers:

The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
    preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for CHAR_BIT and MB_LEN_MAX, the
    following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an
    expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
    promotions. Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude

```
(absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
-- number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
   CHAR_BIT                                            8
-- minimum value for an object of type signed char
   SCHAR_MIN                                -127 // -(27 - 1)
-- maximum value for an object of type signed char
   SCHAR_MAX                                +127 // 27 - 1
-- maximum value for an object of type unsigned char
   UCHAR_MAX                                 255 // 28 - 1
-- minimum value for an object of type char
   CHAR_MIN                               see below
-- maximum value for an object of type char
   CHAR_MAX                              see below
-- maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character, for any supported locale
   MB_LEN_MAX                                    1
-- minimum value for an object of type short int
   SHRT_MIN                               -32767 // -(215 - 1)
-- maximum value for an object of type short int
   SHRT_MAX                               +32767 // 215 - 1
-- maximum value for an object of type unsigned short int
   USHRT_MAX                               65535 // 216 - 1
-- minimum value for an object of type int
   INT_MIN                                 -32767 // -(215 - 1)
-- maximum value for an object of type int
   INT_MAX                                +32767 // 215 - 1
-- maximum value for an object of type unsigned int
   UINT_MAX                                65535 // 216 - 1
-- minimum value for an object of type long int
   LONG_MIN                         -2147483647 // -(231 - 1)
-- maximum value for an object of type long int
   LONG_MAX                         +2147483647 // 231 - 1
-- maximum value for an object of type unsigned long int
   ULONG_MAX                         4294967295 // 232 - 1
-- minimum value for an object of type long long int
   LLONG_MIN          -9223372036854775807 // -(263 - 1)
-- maximum value for an object of type long long int
   LLONG_MAX          +9223372036854775807 // 263 - 1
-- maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int
   ULLONG_MAX         18446744073709551615 // 264 - 1
```

From http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1