# Two -Wformat warnings (unknown conversion type & too many arguments for format)

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned, unsigned-long-long-int

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int the_num = 600851475143;
    
    printf("%llu", the_num);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following warnings:

```
3.c: In function 'main':
3.c:10:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]
  printf("%llu", the_num);
            ^
3.c:10:9: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
  printf("%llu", the_num);
         ^~~~~~
```

Maybe it's just a bug or something?..

GCC version:

`gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)`

Compiled using the following command:

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic 3.c`

Comment: [This does not reproduce with current versions of GCC, Clang, or MSVC.](https://godbolt.org/z/E6sdn6vdq) State the compiler version you are using and the switches used to compile.

Comment: I have the same issue. The GCC version 8 I'm using doesn't recognize a few format specifiers.

Comment: @Haris and I am very curious why.

Comment: Looks like [lack of support in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590735/printf-long-long-int-in-c-with-gcc).

Comment: @Haris have you tried using ```-std=c99``` flag while compiling? It worked for me.

Comment: Rodion Iskhakov, Tip: best to use suffix `u` when assigning constants to an _unsigned_ type, especially when the constant is large.  `unsigned long long int the_num = 600851475143u;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the language standard to `c99` by adding `-std=c99` flag while compiling and the warnings disappeared.

Comment: The warning is so misleading it should be considered a bug. The compiler knows about `long long` types, it was just instructed to consider them unsupported. Thus the warning should read: `warning: unsigned long long conversion unsupported in current configuration [-Wformat=]`