# sscanf won't scan hexadecimal formatted float with "%a" under mingw

Tags: c, floating-point, hex, mingw, scanf

I am using gcc 4.6.1 with mingw in windows.

I recently learned about the `%a` format specifier for representing floats exactly in floating-point hex notation (in C99, apparently).

For some reason I can print a float this way just fine, but I am having trouble scanning it.

If I replace both instances of `%a`, with `%f` my code handles printing and scanning the the floating point number just fine.

The code seems to work just fine when I ran it on a traditional Unix system (gcc 4.2.1).

I have tried every variation I could think of with floats and doubles.  I tried adding the flag `-std=c99`, which seemed to change whether it treated the numeric literal as a double or float, but it did not fix my problem.

I want to know 2 things, if anyone else can duplicate this problem, and what I might do to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char buffer[1000];
    sprintf(buffer, "%la", 21.3930);

    double x = 0;
    printf("\n");
    printf(buffer);

    if(!sscanf(buffer, "%la", &x))
        printf("\nscan failed.");
    printf("\n%la", x);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x1.5649bap+4
scan failed.
0x0.000000p+0
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MinGW uses `msvcrt.dll` for the major part of its C runtime support.  `msvcrt.dll` generally doesn't support C99 functionality.

There are some versions of MinGW that provide their own support for C99 I/O specifiers, but I haven't collected good information on exactly what versions support what C99 features.

See the following for some additional details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136886/12711
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10680635/12711

**Update**:  It looks like the [TDM-64 distribution of MinGW](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) (version 4.6.1) supports the C99 specifiers in the `scanf()` family of functions with prefixed names such as:

```
__mingw_sscanf()
__mingw_scanf()
```

It might be that support is improved in versions newer than 4.6.1 (it looks like that at least as of version 4.6.1 these functions are not in the 32-bit version of the TDM distribution - keep in mind that TDM-64 is capable of building 32-bit binaries as well as 64-bit binaries).

You can use a simple set of macros to 'redirect' the normal names to these functions.

Example output:

```
C:\temp>gcc --version
gcc (tdm64-1) 4.6.1

C:\temp>gcc -m32 -std=gnu99 -o test test.c

C:\temp>test

0xa.b24dd2f1a9fcp+1
0xa.b24dd2f1a9fcp+1
```

Comment: Additionally, you can define `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` when compiling and all functions that mingw has named as `__mingw_funcname()` will automatically be used by default. From here: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/