# C - scanf unsigned char

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to use `scanf()` for reading an unsigned char value with `%hhu`, but the compiler returned me:

```
error: unknown conversion type character 'h' in format
 [-Werror=format]| // line 3 error: too many arguments for format
 [-Werror=format-extra-args]| // line 3
```

With this following code:

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
unsigned char nb;
scanf("%hhu", &nb); // line 3
printf("Number: %u\n", nb);
return (nb);
```

Comment: You are using codeblocks or some other compiler that doesn't respect the `h` format type modifier. Just change everything to `%u` and use `unsigned int`. If you need to read a `byte` use `char`.

Comment: Try adding `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` at the top of the file or add `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` to your preprocessor (or compiler) flags. You seem to be using a MinGW compiler, based on the diagnostic output you've provided. See [this related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10678124/539810) also.

Comment: Add -std=c99 to the compiler options? Just guessing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. It (IIRC) uses GCC as the compiler.

Comment: You are 100% correct. IIRC it is one of the compilers code blocks generally works with (mingw gcc) that doesn't respect the `h` type modifier for `scanf` - my bad.

Comment: I already added -std=c99, @ChronoKitsune it doesn't work

Comment: Oh right, C::B is the problem.. thank's I'm gonna use an unsigned int @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: As a general note, unless you need to read a *byte*, then use the native types `int` or `unsigned` in your code. It will be faster because the compiler is not required to make a type-conversion from `int` to `char`, etc. If you need to limit your read to a byte use `%c` for char. The length modifiers `h` are nice, but are not implemented by all compilers. I've been bitten by this before.

Answer (score 1):

A discussion on this issue can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723798/thread/abd418da/).
This is specific to MinGW.
From [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723798/thread/abd418da/#be67) comment in the discussion the issue is identified as:

> This is most likely related to bug https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/652/ in that the include order and compiler driver actually screws things up with respect to C standard output and format specifiers.

And is proposed solution is:

> to always define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO so that the newer ansi format specifiers can be used and to ensure that long double (at least) is not passed between MSVC compiled and gcc compiled code.