# Why does scanf set the first value to 0?

Tags: c, char, scanf, conversion-specifier

I am using `scanf` to get an input. But when I run this code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  unsigned char in,b;
  scanf("%u %u",&in,&b);
  printf("%u %u\n",in,b);
  return 0;
}
```

when I input, for example, `12 3` , the output is `0 3`.

This also happends when I instead of `scanf("%u %u",&in,&b);` write `scanf("%u",&in);scanf("%u",&b);`.

Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: `%u` is not the right specifier for `unsigned char`. Use `%hhu`.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting warnings about `unsigned int*` being expected.

Comment: Don't ignore warnings. Also, if you have doubts, you can and should include the warnings in your question!

Comment: Because it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks, but why is the value overriden when there are two inputs and not with just one?

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Now I get warning: `unknown conversion type character 'h' in format [-Wformat=]` and the result is the same, locally, but online it works.

Comment: Are you on windows/mingw? I think these might be not supporting this specifier.

Comment: Yes, I am, I am using Code::Blocks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678124/mingw-gcc-unknown-conversion-type-character-h-snprintf As a first step, try updating your MinGW/gcc

Comment: markoj, Why did you ignore warning about `unsigned int*` being expected?

Comment: What if a try using `unsigned int`s for the input and then just masking them with `&0xff`? It works online.

Comment: You certainly can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call of scanf

```
unsigned char in,b;
scanf("%u %u",&in,&b);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the function expects that its second and third arguments are pointers to objects of the type `unsigned int` while actually they are pointers to objects of the type `unsigned char`.

Instead you have to use the length modifier `hh` with the conversion specifier `u`

```
scanf("%hhu %hhu",&in,&b);
```

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> 11 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **hh** Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, X, or n conversion specifier applies to an argument with type **pointer to signed char**
> or **unsigned char**.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition, in case of the `%hhu` conversion specifier being unavailable, you can do:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
unsigned char inp_u8(void){
    unsigned int x;
    scanf("%u",&x);
    return x&0xFF;
}
```